# Limit file size when generate it in php

Tags: php

I have a generator of chars which generate each combination of char from a-Az-Z. The problem is that the file get very bigger if the combinations are higher number.

For example - all variations with 4 letters - `aaaa, aaab,...AAAA, AAAB...zzzz, ZZZZ`. If letters are 5 the file is ~1,8GB. I want to limit the file to 1GB

```
$charLength = 5;
function print_combinations($characters, $length, $combination = '') {
        if ($length > 0) {
            foreach ($characters as $i) {
                print_combinations($characters, $length - 1, $combination . $i);
            }
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", $combination);
        }
}

$characters = array_merge(range('A', 'Z'), range('a', 'z'));

$content = rand(print_combinations($characters, $charLength), $charLength);

$file   = fopen("test1.txt", "w");

$pieces = str_split($content, 1024 * 4);
foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
    fwrite($file, $piece, strlen($piece));
}

fclose($file);
```

Here I have two problems - It doesn't create and write in the file and how to limit the file size?

Note: if I run the file via console `php index.php` it is run normally and printing all the combinations.

Terminal ss
[image]

Comment: Your `print_combinations()` function doesn't return anything, but you seem to think it does.

Comment: But I see it on the terminal when run the file

Comment: You see what the `printf` call outputs. But you want to return a string with that function, not print the result. See [sprintf documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) (notice the extra *s*) - it will return the formatted string instead of printing it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware is right. You are basically calculating a random number beetween null (0) and `$charLength`, which is stored in the test1.txt. I want to add to be careful about using recursion for this solution. If the `$charLength` will get bigger you may encounter a problem of Out of Stack memory.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem 1

As suggested from @KIKOSoftware in the comments, the print_combinations function doesn't return anything. A possible solution might be the one below:

```php
<?php

$charLength = 3;
function print_combinations($characters, $length, $combination = ''){
    if ($length > 0) {
        $combinations = '';
        foreach ($characters as $i) {
            $combinations .= print_combinations($characters, $length - 1, $combination . $i);
        }
        return $combinations;
    } else {
        printf("%s\n", $combination);
        return $combination;
    }
}

$combinations = '';
$characters = array_merge(range('A', 'Z'), range('a', 'z'));
$content = print_combinations($characters, $charLength, $combinations);

$file = fopen("test1.txt", "w");

$pieces = str_split($content, 1024 * 4);
foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
    fwrite($file, $piece, strlen($piece));
}

fclose($file);
```

## Problem 2

You have multiple solutions about this problem. You can check every time you write a new combination in the file his current size with

```php
$filesize = filesize("test1.txt");
```

Otherwise since the file is created with us-ascii encode, so you can estimate the number of combination it can contain in 1GB of memory:

in ASCII you have 1 Byte per character so you can easly calculate how many combinations you can store:

```
$number_of_combinations = 1000000000 / $charLength
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still nothing is written in the file. I'm not sure I understand about the number of combination count

Comment: Does the `test1.txt` file alredy exist or is autogenerated when you launch the php script? Do you have writing permission for the `test1.txt` file?

Comment: About the number of combination, you can't create smaller files, so if you need to block the file writing when it reaches 1GB, you can calculate how many combinations the file can store in 1GB of memory (considering 1 Byte per character in the file). For example if `$charLenght` is 5 you have 48^5 (254803968) combinations which are 1.3 GB aproximately, meanwhile the `$number_of_combination` to have a 1GB, are 200000000.

Comment: Yes, the file exists and I have writing permissions to it. What can be the reason of not writing to it in this case? Also, can you provide simple example for detect the file size and stop writing to the file if reach certain size?